# What window manager should I use as example?

Tags: linux, window-managers

I want to implement a simple specialized window manager for presentations (not user-controllable) that supports only the following operations:

1. Moving and resizing of windows
2. Switching desktops
3. Starting applications not on current desktop (in background) without disrupting current image.

I don't need any user input, button/titles, ...

What existing window manager should I use as example? There are many little "hello world" window managers, but they usually does not support desktop switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reimplement the wheel.

- **[openbox](http://openbox.org/)** will do everything you mention and more besides.

  Simply edit the [rc.xml](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aConfiguration) to disable the root menu, and re-launch.

  Openbox also allows [per app setting](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aApplications) so that certain applications can open on a particular desktop by default, or with a particular size, or open hidden.

  It also supports wildcards in the window selection, so that settings can apply to all windows.
- **[devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/)** is a window matching utility that can perform actions whenever a window opens.

  It is highly hackable and the code is [available on github](https://github.com/gusnan/devilspie2). It will match windows by name/class/etc when they open, and perform actions on them. (including matching all windows and moving them to a different desktop. It will work with most window managers.

  Based on the original [devilspie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie) which does not have Lua scripting, but is configured using s-exprs instead.
- **[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)** will also allow you to perform complex actions on windows without hacking any code. It will even fake user input (mouse/kbd) if you need it.

Comment: OK, will try openbox. The main point is controlling on what desktop to show new windows (not by window class/name). Started applications must prepare their things in background.

Comment: Openbox allows, in the `rc.xml` file, to open windows on a particular desktop based on their X properties.

Comment: I need it to open _all_ windows on desktop N. Then to switch to desktop N and open _all_ new windows on desktop M. May be I'll end up using patched openbox (or awesome or other not bloated WM).

Comment: See update. There's also a standalone utility that does exactly what you ask, but the name escapes me.

Comment: The utility is called devilspie

Comment: Will moving a window away using devilspie2 work seamless, e.g. without chance of "flashing" it on current desktop? Like if I suspend devilspie2 new clients will wait without mapping their windows until I resume devilspie2.

Comment: openbox open-on will definitely work without flashing. IIRC, so does devilspie. Have never tested what you're trying to do, so can't tell you. You'll have to try it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few window managers written in Python that could be good starting points. [Qtile](http://qtile.org/) and [whimsy](http://incise.org/whimsy.html) both describe themselves as hackable.